# IIS Setting for wildcard character

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

Is there any setting changes in IIS to support wildcard character? I am running a web application but IIS does not support wildcard character.

Answer (score 1):

[Installing Wildcard Application Mappings (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true)

IIS 6.0 - Windows 2003 Server

- Open property page for website / virtual directory.
- Click the 'home directory' tab
- Click the 'configuration' button, select the 'mappings' tab
- Click 'insert' next to the 'Wildcard application maps' section
  [image]
- Browse to the aspnet_isapi.dll (normally at c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll)
  [image]
- Ensure that 'check that file exists' is unchecked
- Click OK, OK, OK to close and apply changes

Comment: Pls tell me How can i installit.

Comment: I have iis6.0.pls tell me process.

Comment: Did you get the wildcard configured?

Comment: yup i do change.bt it still does not show output.Which script is mapped in extensions list.my application is in asp.net

Comment: i do as per ur instructions.still prob is same